# is there a way to convert a python script into one class or a package?

Tags: python-3.x, class, package, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am migrating data from IBM to Snowflake in
3 stages- extract, transform and load.

Below is the python code that connects source IBM and destination Snowflake which does the ETL.
is there any way I can create a class/ package out of the entire below code?

```
import snowflake.connector


tableName='F58001'

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='*',
password='*',
account='*.azure'
)

cs = ctx.cursor()

ctx.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE STORE_PROFILE")
ctx.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA LANDING")


try:
ctx.cursor().execute("PUT file:///temp/data/{tableName}/* @%{tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
except Exception:
pass

ctx.cursor().execute("truncate table {tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
ctx.cursor().execute("COPY INTO {tableName} ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE'  ".format(tableName=tableName, 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '""', sometimes=',', ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = 'TRUE'))

last_query_id= ctx.cursor().execute("select last_query_id()")

for res in last_query_id:
query_id = res[0]

ctx.cursor().execute(f"create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from 
table(validate("+tableName+", job_id=> "+"'"+query_id+"'"+"))")

ax = ctx.cursor().execute("select * from save_copy_errors")

for errors in ax:
error = errors
print(error)

ctx.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Every Python file can already be used as a module.

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to factor your code into functions or classes?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am basically trying to see options of packaging this code so that it can be called multiple times (want to run for 5 tables parallely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the below repository. It probably has answer to your question. I am currently working on moving it to PYPI so that it can be installed with PIP

https://github.com/Infosys/Snowflake-Python-Development-Framework